# Is using nested for-loops better than nested while-loops?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program for which I have to use nested loops to  perform a number of coin tosses entered by the user. And I have made a sentinel value and if user does not enter the sentinel value, then the program repeats. Right now, I have an infinite loop that I'm trying to get out of, but my question is whether while loops is the best for this program.

Are for-loops a better option? This code is a bit of a mess, but I'm still working on it.
I'm not asking for help debugging the code, but any hints will be useful! Thank you and here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
  srand(time(0));

  int nCoinTosses = 0;
    cout << "How many times would you like to perform the  coin toss(Enter 0 to quit)?" << endl; 
    cin >> nCoinTosses;
    cin.ignore(1000, 10);

int i = 0; //counter
while (true)
{ 
    while (true)
    {
      if (nCoinTosses == 0) break;
      int choice = rand() % 2;
      if (nCoinTosses == 0) break;

      if (choice == 0)
        cout << "Heads" << endl; 

      if (choice == 1)
        cout << "Tails" << endl; 
        i++;

      if (i == nCoinTosses) break; 
     }//while
  }//while
}
```

Comment: "Better" in what sense?  Your inner loop looks like a `do`/`while` loop would work.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Hmm I was wondering if it would be more efficient? Like would it take less lines of code? I'll try the do while--thanks!

Comment: Your inner loop is a glorified for-loop.  You always increment `i`, and break out of the loop after reaching `nCoinTosses`.  The entire loop could be written as `for(int i = 0; i < nCoinTosses; i++) cout << (rand() % 2 ? "Tails" : "Heads") << endl;`

Comment: By the time the compiler is through with it, a loop is a loop. Eg: `while (x < y)` is the same as `for ( ;  x < y; )` and `for ( x = 0; x < y; x++) { dostuff() }` is the same as `x = 0; while x < y) { dostuff();  x++;}` The only real difference is where the exit condition is tested. Use the loop that is the easiest for you (and hopefully everyone else) to read.

Comment: If `nCoinTosses` is equal to 0, then you have an **infinite loop**!. You break from the inside loop, loop the outside loop, enter the inside loop with same value of 0. **In this case, it is useless to have a nested loop** as the outer loop does nothing. You would get the same behavior by removing it and replacing `break` by `continue` in the inner loop. **Final note**: you usually select the type of loop that make more readable code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really depends on what you are trying to achieve with these loops. Currently, it won't ever break out of your first infinite loop. Is this intentional?

How do you want the program to execute?
After every iteration, should you ask the user if they want to run again?

I would do something like this

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int nCoinTOsses = 0;
    do {
        cout << "How many..."
        cin >> nCoinTosses;
        cin.ignore();
        for( int i = 0; i < nCoinTosses; ++i )
        {
            if( rand % 2 == 0 )
            {
                cout << "Heads";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Tails";
             }
        }
    } while( nCoinTosses != 0 );
}
```

Rationale for the changes: reduce number of variables and no need to use breaks here and there. Having two while(true) statements and breaks just makes the code harder to read and understand.

I would say focus on making the code more readable and then look to make the code more efficient. You added unnecessary complexity to your code by adding random breaks here and there and two while loops (nothing wrong with it) that do not really have any meaning on their own.

`while( nCoinTosses != 0 )` and `for( int i = 0; i <nCoinTosses)` provide a bit more context to what the loops are doing. Rather than having to look for breaks and if conditions.

---

Comment: thank you for the suggestions! Haha and the first infinite loop was not intentional, I wanted it to loop only to the beginning of the program so that the user could type in again how many tosses they wanted.

Comment: No problem. Glad they were helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can write it with a for loop that is perhaps more readable. Here is an example

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
  srand(time(NULL));
  int nCoinTosses = 0;
  cout << "How many times would you like to perform the "
          " coin toss(Enter 0 to quit)?"
       << endl;
  cin >> nCoinTosses;
  for (int i = nCoinTosses; i > 0; i--)
  {
    if (rand() % 2)
      cout << "Heads" << endl;
    else
      cout << "Tails" << endl;
  }
}
```